# Why doesn't Graphene have a band gap?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, graphene, fermis-golden-rule

Is there any simple justification about graphene having no band gap? How bout its linear E-K? Why bilayer graphene has a quadratic E-K and electric field can open a band gap there?

I do not completely understand the broken symmetry argument? 
Also Why MoS2 which has similar structure, do not have similar properties?

I know that we can create the Hamiltonian, plot the band-structure numerically and answer these questions. But I want to know if we can use some simple quantum theory arguments (like perturbation theory, or Fermi golden rule) or symmetry facts to get a qualitative answer for all of these questions.

Comment: I am curious as to why you think graphene should have a band gap? And why do you feel that MoS2, which contains two atomic species, has a similar structure to graphene which contains only one?

Comment: 1) Bilayer graphene has a band gap under application of vetical field. 2) Both of them have hexagonal crystal structure.

Comment: Ah! So it takes some symmetry breaking to produce a band gap. That's interesting. What's even better is that it's tunable. Very cool!